# Месяц и день

Tags: дата, php

У меня есть номер месяца и дня этого месяца.

Мне необходимо найти время этой даты, учитывая, что этот день раньше чем сегодня (или сегодня), но самый ближайший

Примеры (учитывая, что сегодня 1 октября)

```
месяц = 09
день = 1
дата = 1346450400
(01.09.2012)

месяц = 10
день = 1
дата = 1349042400
(01.10.2012)

месяц = 11
день = 1
дата = 1320102000
(01.11.2011)
```

Comment: а поподробнее можно а тто совсем что то не уловил вопрос

Comment: Мне нужно найти дату определенного дня по данным мне дню и дате, но с условием, что этот день раньше, чем сегодня или сегодня.

То есть, если мне дано $day=1; $month=10; то он мне дает timestamp 1-го октября этого года, т.к. этот день сегодня.

Если мне дано $day=1; $month=9; то он мне дает timestamp 1-го сентября этого года, т.к. этот день уже был и это ближайший 1-й сентябрь относительно этого дня.

Ну а если мне дано $day=1; $month=11; то он мне дает timestamp 1-го ноября предыдущего года, я думаю, что остальное ясно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы всё правильно придумали. Только лучше сравнивать время на конец дня, и, наверное, по UTC:

```
$bfe = gmmktime(23,59,59,$start['month'],$start['day']) <= time() ?
gmmktime(0,0,0,$start['month'],$start['day']) :
gmmktime(0,0,0,$start['month'],$start['day'],date('Y')-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (mktime(0,0,0,$start['month'],$start['day'])<=mktime())
    $bfe = mktime(0,0,0,$start['month'],$start['day']);
else
    $bfe = mktime(0,0,0,$start['month'],$start['day'],(date('Y')-1));
```

Искренне надеюсь, что предложите лучше.